How to use polars expressions for indexing and slicing an external list?
I have a polars dataframe with three columns: audio_idx, i_start, and i_stop. I also have an external list of numpy arrays. audio_idx refers to the index of the external list, while i_start and i_stop refer to a slice of the numpy array.
Here's an example:
audios = [(np.random.rand(10)*10).astype(int) for _ in range(3)]
df = pl.DataFrame({"audio_idx": [0,0,1,2], "i_start": [1,6,6,3], "i_stop": [4,8,9,5]})

audios:
[array([9, 8, 6, 2, 2, 9, 5, 4, 7, 9]),
  array([4, 2, 8, 4, 6, 1, 0, 4, 0, 7]),
  array([3, 2, 6, 9, 6, 8, 8, 8, 0, 1])]

df
 shape: (4, 3)
 ┌───────────┬─────────┬────────┐
 │ audio_idx ┆ i_start ┆ i_stop │
 │ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---    │
 │ i64       ┆ i64     ┆ i64    │
 ╞═══════════╪═════════╪════════╡
 │ 0         ┆ 1       ┆ 4      │
 │ 0         ┆ 6       ┆ 8      │
 │ 1         ┆ 6       ┆ 9      │
 │ 2         ┆ 3       ┆ 5      │
 └───────────┴─────────┴────────┘

I want the following output:
shape: (4, 4)
┌───────────┬─────────┬────────┬───────────┐
│ audio_idx ┆ i_start ┆ i_stop ┆ audio     │
│ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╪═════════╪════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 1       ┆ 4      ┆ [8, 6, 2] │
│ 0         ┆ 6       ┆ 8      ┆ [5, 4]    │
│ 1         ┆ 6       ┆ 9      ┆ [0, 4, 0] │
│ 2         ┆ 3       ┆ 5      ┆ [9, 6]    │
└───────────┴─────────┴────────┴───────────┘

I am able to achieve this with map_elements the following way:
df = df.with_columns(
    audio=pl.struct(["audio_idx", "i_start", "i_stop"]).map_elements(
        lambda x: audios[x["audio_idx"]][x["i_start"] : x["i_stop"]].tolist(),
        return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Int64),
    )
)

However, is there way to use polars expressions instead of map_elements? I would prefer to use the external list still, rather than copying the full numpy array into each row, as this saves me memory. Thank you.

In line with @Roman Pekar's solution, you can create another DataFrame from your numpy array.
However instead of creating an index and explicitly joining on that, you can combine these two frames using with_context(…) with a .gather expression.
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from polars import col

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

audios = [rng.integers(100, size=10) for _ in range(3)]
audio_df = pl.DataFrame({'audios': audios})
df = pl.DataFrame({"audio_idx": [0,0,1,2], "i_start": [1,6,6,3], "i_stop": [4,8,9,5]})

print(
    df.lazy().with_context(audio_df.lazy())
    .with_columns(
        col('audios').gather(col('audio_idx'))
        .list.slice(col('i_start'), col('i_stop') - col('i_start'))
    )
    .collect()
)
# shape: (4, 4)
# ┌───────────┬─────────┬────────┬──────────────┐
# │ audio_idx ┆ i_start ┆ i_stop ┆ audios       │
# │ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---          │
# │ i64       ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ list[i64]    │
# ╞═══════════╪═════════╪════════╪══════════════╡
# │ 0         ┆ 1       ┆ 4      ┆ [63, 51, 26] │
# │ 0         ┆ 6       ┆ 8      ┆ [7, 1]       │
# │ 1         ┆ 6       ┆ 9      ┆ [63, 54, 55] │
# │ 2         ┆ 3       ┆ 5      ┆ [0, 39]      │
# └───────────┴─────────┴────────┴──────────────┘

You can also do this in a pure eager formulation like so:
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
from polars import col

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

audios = [rng.integers(100, size=10) for _ in range(3)]
df = pl.DataFrame({"audio_idx": [0,0,1,2], "i_start": [1,6,6,3], "i_stop": [4,8,9,5]})

print(
    df.with_columns(
        audios=(
            pl.Series(audios).gather(df['audio_idx'])
            .list.slice(df['i_start'], df['i_stop'] - df['i_start'])
        )
    )
)
# shape: (4, 4)
# ┌───────────┬─────────┬────────┬──────────────┐
# │ audio_idx ┆ i_start ┆ i_stop ┆ audios       │
# │ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---          │
# │ i64       ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ list[i64]    │
# ╞═══════════╪═════════╪════════╪══════════════╡
# │ 0         ┆ 1       ┆ 4      ┆ [63, 51, 26] │
# │ 0         ┆ 6       ┆ 8      ┆ [7, 1]       │
# │ 1         ┆ 6       ┆ 9      ┆ [63, 54, 55] │
# │ 2         ┆ 3       ┆ 5      ┆ [0, 39]      │
# └───────────┴─────────┴────────┴──────────────┘


if you create another DataFrame from your numpy array:
adf = pl.DataFrame({"audio_idx": range(len(audios)), "audio": audios})

┌───────────┬─────────────┐
│ audio_idx ┆ audio       │
│ ---       ┆ ---         │
│ i64       ┆ list[i32]   │
╞═══════════╪═════════════╡
│ 0         ┆ [9, 8, … 9] │
│ 1         ┆ [4, 2, … 7] │
│ 2         ┆ [3, 2, … 1] │
└───────────┴─────────────┘

you can then use DataFrame.join and Expr.list.slice() to get the result:
(
    df
    .join(adf, on="audio_idx")
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("audio").list.slice(pl.col("i_start"), pl.col("i_stop") - pl.col("i_start"))
    )
)

┌───────────┬─────────┬────────┬───────────┐
│ audio_idx ┆ i_start ┆ i_stop ┆ audio     │
│ ---       ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ i64       ┆ i64     ┆ i64    ┆ list[i32] │
╞═══════════╪═════════╪════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0         ┆ 1       ┆ 4      ┆ [8, 6, 2] │
│ 0         ┆ 6       ┆ 8      ┆ [5, 4]    │
│ 1         ┆ 6       ┆ 9      ┆ [0, 4, 0] │
│ 2         ┆ 3       ┆ 5      ┆ [9, 6]    │
└───────────┴─────────┴────────┴───────────┘

